# 2 users login in 1 form in the CodeIgniter framework (multi level login system)

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-3

I´m working on a website and there are 2 users that are able to login into my website, both users are different tables in my database:

```
1. administrator
2. werknemer
```

For both of those users I have a different login form and login controller function, but what I want is that both users can login in just 1 form.
I just don't know how to do that.

These are the 2 view forms in my login.php view file:

```
  <?php  echo form_open('index.php/Auth/werknemer_login'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="naam" id="naam" type="text" placeholder="Naam">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="wachtwoord" id="wachtwoord" type="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
                </div>

                <a href="" id="wachtwoordvergeten">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a>



                <br>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="werknemer_login" >Inloggen</button>
                    <br><br><br><br>
                </div>
            </form>



        </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>


    <!-- ----------------verticale lijn-------------------- -->



    <!-- ----------------Administrator inloggen-------------------- -->
    <div class="main1" id="administrator_login">
            <br>
            <h3 class="headerh3">Administrator inloggen</h3>
               <?php  echo form_open('index.php/Auth/administrator_login'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="naam" id="naam" type="text" placeholder="Naam">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="wachtwoord" id="wachtwoord" type="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord">
                </div>

                <a href="" id="wachtwoordvergeten">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a>



                <br>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="administrator_login" >Inloggen</button>
                    <br><br><br><br>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And these are the login controller functions in my Auth.php controllers:

```
public function administrator_login()
    {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('naam', 'Naam', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('wachtwoord', 'Wachtwoord', 'required|min_length[5]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

                $naam = $_POST['naam'];
                $wachtwoord = ($_POST['wachtwoord']);


                //check gebruiker in database
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('administrator');
                $this->db->where(array('naam'=>$naam));
                $query = $this->db->get();
                $administrator = $query->row();


                //Als gebruiker bestaat
                if($administrator->naam) 
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("success","U bent nu ingelogd als administrator");
                    //Als er een user is maak session date
                        $_SESSION['administrator_level'] = 1; 
                        $_SESSION['administrator_logged'] = TRUE; 
                        $_SESSION['naam'] = $administrator->naam;
                        $_SESSION['wachtwoord'] = $administrator->wachtwoord;

                  //link naar werknemer/administrator view pagina
                 redirect("index.php/Welkomadministrator", "refresh");
                }
                $this->session->set_flashdata("success","U bent nu ingelogd");
                }
                else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Verkeerde naam of wachtwoord');
                //wanneer er een foutmelding is link weer naar de login pagina
                redirect("" , "refresh");
            }

                  //laad de login pagina
              //    $this->load->view('login');

    }


    // Login code voor de administrator
    public function werknemer_login()
    {       
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('naam', 'Naam', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('wachtwoord', 'Wachtwoord', 'required|min_length[5]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {

                $naam = $_POST['naam'];
                $wachtwoord = ($_POST['wachtwoord']);


                //check gebruiker in database
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from('werknemer');
                $this->db->where(array('naam'=>$naam));
                $query = $this->db->get();
                $werknemer = $query->row();


                //Als gebruiker bestaat
                 if($werknemer->naam) 
                 {
                     $this->session->set_flashdata("success","U bent nu ingelogd als werknemer");
                        //Als er een user is maak session date
                        $_SESSION['werknemer_level'] = 1; 
                        $_SESSION['werknemer_logged'] = TRUE; 
                        $_SESSION['naam'] = $werknemer->naam;
                        $_SESSION['wachtwoord'] = $werknemer->wachtwoord;
                 }       
              //link naar administrator/werknemer view pagina
                 redirect("index.php/Welkomwerknemer", "refresh");

                $this->session->set_flashdata("success","U bent nu ingelogd");
                }

                else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Verkeerde naam of wachtwoord');
                //wanneer er een foutmelding is link weer naar de login pagina
                redirect("" , "refresh");
                }
                  //laad de login pagina
                  //$this->load->view('login');
            }
```

So my question is is there a way to have 2 users login 1 form?

Comment: I have a bit of a suggestion: why not just have both admin and regular users in the same db table? this prevents duplicate logic that may occur from fetching results from different tables. simply add a field `group` or a table `group` related to the users table and specify whether or not the user is an `admin` or `werknemer`. Your function also has a bit of a logical issue in that it doesn't have an else if the user isn't found in the db - you also don't seem to check if the password is correct?

Comment: Also do your tables have a unique id column?

Comment: So in my werknemer table I should add a new column called admin? and yes my tables do have unique id columns, werknemer_id and administrator_id

Comment: I would just have a table called users and then have both users in it. Have an unique autoincremented id column, username, email, hashed password .etc. then yes, a column called admin where you have 1 if admin 0 if not. If you need more grouping options then a separate table or a column called groups where you put all the groups a user belongs to or a table called groups related to the users id. I would also suggest you check out ion auth. Will save you time and is more secure. I noticed you aren't even checking if the users password is correct and your storing plaintext passwords...

Comment: Than how should I store my passwords? And I have alot of functions made so I will not change my database tables, is there no single way to do this with 2 database tables?

Comment: And what do you mean im not checking if the users password is correct? when I type a wrong password into the form it won't login

Comment: The variable wachtword isn't used anywhere. According to your logic you can just login by typing in a correct username. Unless these aren't the only functions involved in logging in a user... And passwords need to be hashed before storing in databade: lookup password verify php function

Comment: When I only type a correct username it won't let me login. And these are the only login functions I have

Comment: Do you know some good tutorial on how to hash passwords in CI?

Comment: Bro you can clearly see in the logic that wachtword isn't being used except as a session variable (which is weird). Type in a correct username and a random password above 5 chars. There is absolutely no logic to prevent wrong passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many ways. One you can add one extra column in login table for role. this reduces one extra table you need. After login you can check what is role of logged in user then redirect him to that page. This is most preferred one.

Second one for one form with two table is first check user entry in admin table if user details are present & correct redirect him to admin page if user details are not there then check other table then redirect to regular user page(if credentials are correct).

Lets say there is no user details in both table then this indicates either that user is not registered or entered wrong id.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a few errors that were documented in the comments. Using the following code you can login both user groups from the same controller while maintaining your current table structure. I would like to add that this will not work out of the box - you will have to use the `hash_password()` in the model to hash any plain-text passwords you currently have stored in the db - this is for your users safety.

**Notice: [as per the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) the password field in the db has to allow for an input equal to or larger 255 characters**

> it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can
>   expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

Controller:

```
class Somecontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function login() {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('naam', 'Naam', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('wachtwoord', 'Wachtwoord', 'required|min_length[5]');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
            redirect('', 'refresh');
        }
        $this->load->model('auth_model');
        $naam = $this->input->post('naam');
        $wachtwoord = $this->input->post('wachtwoord');
        if (($admin = $this->auth_model->get_user($naam, 'administrator')) !== false) {
            if (!$this->auth_model->verify_password($wachtwoord, $admin->wachtwoord)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Name or password is invalid.');
                redirect('', 'refresh');
            }
            $_SESSION['administrator_level'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['administrator_logged'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['naam'] = $admin->naam;
            // Don't store the users password in a session
            //$_SESSION['wachtwoord'] = $admin->wachtwoord;
            $this->session->set_flashdata("success","U bent nu ingelogd");
            redirect('index.php/Welkomadministrator', 'refresh');
        } elseif (($user = $this->auth_model->get_user($naam, 'werknemer')) !== false) {
            if (!$this->auth_model->verify_password($wachtwoord, $user->wachtwoord)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Name or password is invalid.');
                redirect('', 'refresh');
            }
            $_SESSION['werknemer_level'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['werknemer_logged'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['naam'] = $user->naam;
            //$_SESSION['wachtwoord'] = $user->wachtwoord;
            $this->session->set_flashdata("success","U bent nu ingelogd");
            redirect('index.php/Welkomwerknemer', 'refresh');
        } else {
            // we couldn't find the user in either table, they must not exist
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User does not exist in the system.');
            redirect('', 'refresh');
        }
    }

}
```

Model:

```
class Auth_model extends CI_Model {

    /**
     * Gets a user from the db
     * 
     * @param mixed $naam
     * @param string $table
     * @return boolean|obj
     */
    public function get_user($naam, $table) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where($table, array('naam' => $naam));
        if ($query->num_rows() > 1) {
            return $query->row();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Verifies password matches the hashed password stored in db
     * 
     * @param string $password user keyed in password
     * @param string $db_password password from db
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function verify_password($password, $db_password) {
        return password_verify($password, $db_password);
    }

    /**
     * Hashes a password to be stored in db
     * 
     * @param mixed $password
     * @return hashed password
     */
    public function hash_password($password) {
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }

}
```